# Disable hotkeys / autocorrect in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

i am sure this must be covered somewhere (I looked, but honestly could not find): is there a simple way to disable CTRL+ALT hotkeys in Windows 7? currently  - when i type CTRL+ALT+C it auto-inserts ©, and CTRL+ALT+N does ñ, etc. That conflicts with a range of shortcut keys in RStudio - and hence i was wondering if there is a way to disable these character map shortcut keys?

Comment: I tried those shortcuts, and with nothing running, they do noting in a word processor.  So you either have a different keyboard layout or a non-standard application is inserting those characters.  In other words those are non-standard shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

In your Language Preferences settings within Windows select the "US Keyboard" (**not** the "US International" Keyboard, and obviously not any national keyboard that uses Ctrl-Alt combinations for accented characters). This will release the Ctrl-Alt shoutcuts for use by RStudio (or anything else).
You can have multiple keyboard layouts to switch between, even for a single language.